# Thought experiment regarding destructive interference

Tags: energy-conservation, interference, thought-experiment

Considering the following thought experiment: Starting with a cavity with perfect mirrors and a monochromatic electromagnetic wave which matches the distance of the mirrors so that constructive interference is present inside the cavity. Now, if one mirror would be moved so that destructive interference would occur, there would be no Intensity of the monochromatic electromagnetic wave visible anymore. But due to energy conservation the energy of the wave cannot just disappear. So where does the energy go in this case? Or maybe I should better ask: Which of my assumptions cannot be fulfilled and may be the explanation for the contradiction of the energy conservation?

Answer (score 0):

Since you ask for a wave point of view, the reflection in each wall is ideally produced by a perfect mirror (and a perfect conductor), which can change the momentum $\vec{p}$ to $-\vec{p}$ for the electromagnetic wave; that means work is done on the walls (a change in momentum in an infinitesimal time) and therefore the wall would absorb energy and emit energy as needed. You can make a similar argument with the Poynting vector and the flux of energy and momentum for a plane wave.

Comment: Would this then imply that, if the cavity is once aligned to destructive interference and then aligned back to constructive interference condition the electromagnetic filed would not be present inside the cavity anymore, due to absorptions by the mirrors?